# Tiled background image in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

When using OpenLAyers is it possible to have a layer that consists of a tiled, zoomable image? I can use CSS to set the background-image and background-repeat properties of the DIV tag but of course that doesn't scale when I zoom in and out.

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenLayers.Layer.WMS for tiled, zoomable images, which I believe is the most commonly used layer for that purpose.  There is a [simple WMS example](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/wms.html) in the OpenLayers Demos.  If you sniff the http requests made from that demo, you'll see a URL like:

```
http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?LAYERS=basic&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/jpeg&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=5.625,39.375,11.25,45&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256
```

Request parameters in this URL include a bounding box, a projection  and a tile width and height.  The server responds with the appropriately sized image for that location (BBOX) and projection (SRS). OpenLayers takes care of placing the tile images returned into the appropriate locations in your map viewport.

OpenLayers is doing a lot for you here.  You don't have to manipulate the CSS or DIV tags yourself, but it is all done geospatially.  If your tiled images aren't geospatial then you might want to look at something else besided OpenLayers.  Hope I helped.